# Show lines before and after result in fzf

Tags: command-line-interface, fzf

Using [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) I want to be able to see the lines before and after the matched result when making a search. By default only the matched line is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this [feature hasn't been implemented](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/1598) in fzf just yet, (although the author makes no suggestion that it will be in future) but does provide a work around using [fzf --preview](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/1598#issuecomment-514004467)

I don't know if that suits your particular use case but I was trying to find a certain git sha from the git history of repo where I knew a portion of the commit message. I couldn't get it to work with `git log` directly so I sent the whole log to a file, `git_log`, and used that instead:

`fzf --preview 'tail +$(( {n} - 3 )) git_log' < git_log`

(augmented version of the command provided in the Github issue)

`{n} - 3` is 3 lines before the line that's matched, `{n}` being the zero-based index of the matching line.

The preview window should show the previous 3 lines then the line that's matched and then the rest of the `git_log` file until the end of the preview window.